# How to calculate p-value using an algorithm on R assuming that distribution is unknown

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value

For a given sample x, where x is distributed with a normal distribution mean known but variance unknown. I am testing the hypothesis that variance is equal to one or greater than 1. The question is to assume that the distribution of the test statistic is unknown and write an algorithm on R relying on a sampling experiment to calculate the p-value. I have worked out the neyman pearson equivalent test statistic as the sum of the observed x values squared. However every approach I use I use the fact that the test statistic is a chi squared distribution and I dont know any other way to approach it. Any initial pointers on the problem would be a great help. Thank you.

Comment: Remember that *re*sampling is a form of sampling.

Comment: (1) Your test statistic has a [noncentral $\chi^2$ distribution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) (2) An accurate simulation of this test statistic for given sample size `n` and known mean `mu` can be accomplished rapidly using an expression like `stats <- apply(matrix(rnorm(n*1e5, mean=mu), nrow=n)^2, 2, sum)`. Compare its histogram to a plot of `dchisq(x, df=n, ncp=n*mu^2)`.

Comment: @whuber `colSums(matrix(rnorm(n*1e5, mean=mu), nrow=n)^2)` will be a bit faster.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the tip--it's quite a bit faster (by several orders of magnitude).

Comment: @whuber One call to a function mostly implemented in C vs. 1e5 calls to an R function (by a `for` loop hidden in `apply`). `colSums` and friends are very useful.